# Continuity equation in curved space-time: a point particle

Tags: electromagnetism, general-relativity, lagrangian-formalism, conservation-laws, point-particles

Let us consider the action describing a point particle with charge $e$. The interaction term is equal to
$$
S_{int} = e\int A_{\mu}\dfrac{d{x}_e^{\mu}}{d\tau}d\tau = e\int A_{\mu}\dot{x}_e^{\mu}dt
$$

even in curved space-time.

If we take the variation of $S_{int}$ with respect to $A_{\mu}$, we should get the source term for the electromagnetic field as the integrand coefficient of $\delta A_{\mu}$. But first, we must write the action as an integral on $(x,y,z,t)$.  So
$$
S_{int} = \dfrac{e}{c}\int A_{\mu}\dot{x}_e^{\mu}\delta^3(\vec{r}-\vec{r}_e(t))d^4x
$$

and
$$
\delta S_{int} = \dfrac{e}{c}\int \dot{x}_e^{\mu}\delta^3(\vec{r}-\vec{r}_e(t))\delta A_{\mu}d^4x;
$$

the source term would then be $$j^{\mu} = \tfrac{e}{c}\dot{x}_e^{\mu}\delta^3(\vec{r}-\vec{r}_e(t)).$$ This source term has the property that $$\partial_{\mu}j^{\mu} = 0.$$ See
$$
\partial_0j^0 = \dfrac{e}{c}\delta'(x-x_e(t))\delta(y-y_e(t))\delta(z-z_e(t))\left(-\dfrac{dx_e}{dct}\right) + \dfrac{e}{c}\delta(x-x_e(t))\delta'(y-y_e(t))\delta(z-z_e(t))\left(-\dfrac{dy_e}{dct}\right) + \dfrac{e}{c}\delta'(x-x_e(t))\delta(y-y_e(t))\delta'(z-z_e(t))\left(-\dfrac{dz_e}{dct}\right)
$$

$$
\partial_1j^1 = \dfrac{e}{c}\dfrac{dx_e}{dct}\delta'(x-x_e(t))\delta(y-y_e(t))\delta(z-z_e(t))
$$

$$
\partial_2j^2 = \dfrac{e}{c}\dfrac{dy_e}{dct}\delta(x-x_e(t))\delta'(y-y_e(t))\delta(z-z_e(t))
$$

$$
\partial_3j^3 = \dfrac{e}{c}\dfrac{dz_e}{dct}\delta(x-x_e(t))\delta(y-y_e(t))\delta'(z-z_e(t))
$$

so $\partial_{\mu}j^{\mu} = 0$. This is what we'd call the continuity equation in flat space-time. However, it is not clear to me how this would be different inside of a curved space-time. The action term is supposedly the same, so the current density $j^{\mu}$ would be the same as well? What does change here?

Comment: Hint: In GR one needs to include a $\sqrt{|g|}$ factor.